# With Spring-Boot and WebJars how do I configure Swagger-UI

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a Spring-Boot Application, generating swagger JSON at `/contextPath/v2/api-docs`.
Due to security concerns I have installed Swagger-UI from webJars version: 4.1.3.
Swagger-UI no longer allows ?url as a query parameter.

I have tried placing `swagger-config.yaml` and `swagger-config.json` in `/resources/static/` and `/resources/META-INF/resources/`

I have also tried adding a new rest controller for a GET endpoint of
`webpack://SwaggerUIBundle/swagger-config.yaml`

So far nothing has worked.
When I manually paste the endpoint into "Explore" the Docs load.
So I know the problem isn't with my generated swagger JSON.

So How do I get Swagger-UI to load my Swagger JSON when the page loads?

Comment: Hi @Raystorm, did you get solution to this. I am also stuck with the same problem.

Comment: @Rohit My team had different versions with intermittent levels of success.  We ended up migrating from SpringFox-Swagger to OpenApiDocs, It's a lot of work but much more stable, and easier to maintain now.

Answer (score 4):

#### To reproduce the issue, I:

1. [Started simple (maven,web,devtools)](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.0.4&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=web,devtools)
2. Added springdoc (for api-generation)

   ```xml
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
     <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.4</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. Added (current) webjars-swagger-ui:

   ```xml
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
     <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
     <version>4.18.1</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
4. Deactivated springdoc's UI (application.properties):

   ```properties
   springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled=false
   ```
5. Some rudimentary `@RestController` to generate my API at `/v3/api-docs/`..

---

#### Result

We get the "default" swagger UI at `http://localhost:8080/webjars/swagger-ui/index.html` (pointing to `https://petstore.swagger.io` API ...;( ##

---

#### (One possible) Fix/Workaround

Overwriting swagger initializer:

1. Copy `swagger-initalizer.js`

   - from `swagger-ui.<YOUR-VERSION>.jar!/META-INF/resources/webjars/swagger-ui/<YOUR-VERSION>/`
   - to `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/webjars/swagger-ui/<YOUR-VERSION>/`

   (This let's you customize (theoretically any) webjars file. Destination folder is important/may vary with time/spring versions)
2. Modifying it:

   ```js
   ...
   url: "/path/to/your/v2/api-docs"
   ...
   ```

   to your needs/suits.

That's it! (Running the application,) Swagger-ui will point to `/path/to/your/v2/api-docs`.

---

Alternative approaches can be:

- to (appropriately) replace `swagger-config.json`
- to use a custom html/resolver/initialiser

But still wondering, why doesn't/how the "url (configuration) approach" works (as [documented](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md))/since when it is "not allowed").

Thanks to & for more alternatives see also: [Webjars - Add configuration to Swagger-UI webjar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72935736/592355)

Comment: Regarding "disabled url config", I found [this](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4872), but it could be better documented on [configuration page](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md). To reactivate it (which i discourage), we need to set `queryConfigEnabled=true` (...with one of the above methods).